# how to do "adc" INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT IDENTITY in .sql file: adc is coloumn name

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

how to do adc INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT IDENTITY  in .sql file. adc is my coloumn name.
i want this beacuse i am using  tag in spring which takes a script of schema which is of .sql extension. but my embedded database is in hsql. hsql does not support autoincrement so i have to write the create table statement in my .sql file like this :

```
CREATE TABLE personal (
    id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT IDENTITY,
    username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    host_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    port_number varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    database_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
)
```

how i can do the above query in .sql file. please help me as soon as possible
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement needs the addition of "AS" to the IDENTITY definition:

```
CREATE TABLE personal ( id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY, username varchar(45) NOT NULL, password varchar(45) NOT NULL, host_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, port_number varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL, database_name varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL )
```

As another user said in the comment, please go to your previous questions and "accept" the correct answers. If you do not do this, people will not answer your future questions.